# How to bind a range of inputs to one bind command?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was just wondering if it would be possible to shorten this. I'm not too familiar with `tkinter` but this was my attempt.

```
self.window.bind("1", lambda event: self.numPressed(event))
self.window.bind("2", lambda event: self.numPressed(event))
self.window.bind("3", lambda event: self.numPressed(event))
self.window.bind("4", lambda event: self.numPressed(event))
self.window.bind("5", lambda event: self.numPressed(event))
self.window.bind("6", lambda event: self.numPressed(event))
self.window.bind("7", lambda event: self.numPressed(event))
self.window.bind("8", lambda event: self.numPressed(event))
self.window.bind("9", lambda event: self.numPressed(event))
```

Answer (score 4):

`lambda event: self.numPressed(event)` is just `self.numPressed`, and you can use a loop.

So the entire thing is just

```
for n in '123456789':
    self.window.bind(n, self.numPressed)
```